# Is Extended Security Maintenance on-topic?

Tags: discussion

Is Extended Security Maintenance on-topic on AU even though the subject OS is EoSS?

Ubuntu Help states:

**Questions that you may ask:** include:

"Services provided by Ubuntu and Canonical".

ESM is a Canonical service.

Comment: Asking about ESM itself is on topic (ie. what is ESM? How does it work? Etc.) Asking about a release that reached its end of standard support and went into ESM is off topic

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would argue that questions about the ESM program itself, how it works, what it provides etc. would be on topic since we do allow questions about Canonical services and this is a service provided by Canonical.

I also think it would be best to change this policy and limit our scope to the technical side of things since we are *not* Canonical and don't work for them so we shouldn't be answering questions about the company's services, but that would have to be a separate discussion.

So, as long as we explicitly allow questions about Canonical services, we should also consider questions about the details of ESM on topic. This does not meant that technical questions about Ubuntu versions that are no longer actively maintained are on topic (we still can't ask "How can I foo the bar in Ubuntu 16.04?"), but we can ask about the ESM service itself.